# Regex to match pattern until next occurence of it

Tags: python, regex

I have following data:

```
2018-03-20 23:28:47 INFO This is an info sample(can be multiline with new line characters)
2018-03-20 23:28:47 INFO This is an info sample(can be multiline with new line characters)
2018-03-20 23:28:47 DEBUG This is a debug sample(can be multiline with new line characters) {
  'x':1,
  'y':2,
  'z':3,
  'w':4
}
2018-03-20 23:28:47 INFO This is an info sample(can be multiline with new line characters)
2018-03-20 23:28:47 DEBUG This is a debug sample(can be multiline with new line characters){
  'a':5,
  'b':6,
  'c':7,
  'd':8
}
```

I've to extract all DEBUG statements and for that I am using this regex `(\d{4}\-\d{2}\-\d{2}\ \d{2}\:\d{2}\:\d{2}\ DEBUG(.|\n|\r)*?)(?=\d{4}\-\d{2}\-\d{2}\ \d{2}\:\d{2}\:\d{2})` but it is omitting the last DEBUG statement. What should be the regex to obtain following output?

```
2018-03-20 23:28:47 DEBUG This is a debug sample(can be multiline with new line characters) {
  'x':1,
  'y':2,
  'z':3,
  'w':4
}
2018-03-20 23:28:47 DEBUG This is a debug sample(can be multiline with new line characters){
  'a':5,
  'b':6,
  'c':7,
  'd':8
}
```

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: Why not just add an `|\Z` to the final expression - match either the next date **or the end of file**?

Comment: @aditya I am assuming that this data is present in some log file. Why do you want to use regex? You can simply use a `grep` command.

Comment: @Abhi and `grep` uses regular expressions, so we're back where we started!

Comment: See https://regex101.com/r/3ly5ih/1

Comment: I dont know why it was downvoted but I think this is a good question. And answer by Wiktor looks right.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest:

- Anchor the matches at the start of the line to make it safer (by using `(?m)`)
- Fix the current issue by adding an alternative with the very end of the string `\Z` (same as Ken suggests in the comments)
- Replace a very inefficient `(.|\r|\n)*?` pattern with `.*?` and adding a DOTALL modifier `(?s)`

The whole fix will look like

```
(?sm)^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2} DEBUG\s*(.*?)(?=[\r\n]+\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}|\Z)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/3ly5ih/1).

**Details**

- `(?sm)` - DOTALL and MULTILINE options on
- `^` - start of a line
- `\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}` - a timestamp like pattern
- `DEBUG` - a literal substring
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `(.*?)` - Group 1: any 0+ chars, as few as possible, up to but excluding
- `(?=[\r\n]+\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}|\Z)` - a positive lookahead that requires either

  - `[\r\n]+\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}` - one or more CR or LF symbol(s) followed with a timestamp like pattern
  - `|` - or
  - `\Z` - the very end of the string

Answer (score 1):

If you are sure that all the paragraphs with `DEBUG` will end with `}`, you can use:

```
r"(.*DEBUG[\s\S]*?\})"
```

If `DEBUG` may or may not have `{}`, the following regex should do the trick:

```
r"(.*DEBUG.*(?!=\{|\n))(\{[\s\S]*?\})?"
```